# Spliting audio file into overlaping chunks

Tags: math, audio, split, overlap, chunks

This seems to be more of a math problem.

An audio file is of length `L` seconds. We want to split it into equal chunks of length `c` seconds. Each next chunk should have overlap of `ø` seconds with the previous chunk.

Into how many chunks (`N`) can we split this file? And how long is the remaining last chunk `r` (if the whole file can not be divided this way without a remainder)?

---

Example 1:

`L` = 12s, `c` = 4s, `ø` = 1s.

Result: number of chunks of length `c` is `N` = 3, remaining last chunk length `r` = 3s

[Simple image to illustrate this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxTI2.png)

---

Without overlapping finding the number of the chunks and the remainder is just as easy as `N = L / s` and `r = L % s`. But I can't quite come up with a formula or a piece of code for this problem with overlapping. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

N chunks give length:

```
Len = N * (C - F) + F
```

So to get number of uncut chunks we should divide:

```
K = (L - F) / (C - F)
```

The last chunk length (if non-zero) is

```
if ((L - F) % (C - F) > 0)    
        LastLen = L - K * (C - F)
```

Examples:

```
 L = 12  C = 4  F = 1
 K = (12 - 1) / (4 - 1) = 3
 (12 - 1) % (4 - 1) > 0, so
     LastLen = 12 - 3 * 3 = 3

 L = 8  C = 5  F = 2
 K = (8 - 2) / (5 - 2) = 2
 (8 - 2) % (5 - 2)  =  0, so
     LastLen = 0
```